# Center bigger background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, horizontal-scrolling

I've been trying to find a way to center a `w:3000 x h:900px` image as the body background image using only HTML and CSS.

I tried:

```css
html, body{
    width:3000;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/3000x900');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

But it did not work, I also tried:

- Placing the `height:auto;`
- Adding the `height:900px;`
- Replacing width with `width:100%`

But none of which worked.

Then I tried creating a div with the same background image and giving it `margin:0 auto;` like so:

```css
#bg {
    width:2000px;
    height:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/3000x900');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

...but still doesn't work.

I do not need it to resize, I just need it centered on the screen and `overflow-x:hidded;` because I don't want that horizontal scroll to appear at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `background-position` style:

```css
html, body {
    width:3000; /* This style doesn't do anything, did you make a typo? */
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image: bgimage;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/PYUk4/)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes I did, I wrote everything here :D I am used to writing and I can't believe I was so silly into forgetting to place the background-position and remove the width :D It don't even need to try this, I will most certainly work :) Thanks for dealing with my foolishness and silly question.

Comment: PS: Will mark as right question as soon as stackoverflow will let me :D

Comment: Although, just to mention this, replacing the height:100% with the actual image height in pixels will help prevent the image from not being aligned to top when you zoom-out :) If the width is set the 100% , in zoom out the image will not remain aligned to window top :)